# Root detection bypass issue in android

Tags: android, security, root

I've below code to check root detection

```
private static boolean checkRootMethod1() {
        String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
        return buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys");
    }

    private static boolean checkRootMethod2() {
        String[] paths = { "/system/app/Superuser.apk", "/sbin/su",
                "/system/bin/su", "/system/xbin/su", "/data/local/xbin/su",
                "/data/local/bin/su", "/system/sd/xbin/su",
                "/system/bin/failsafe/su", "/data/local/su" };
        for (String path : paths) {
            if (new File(path).exists())
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean checkRootMethod3() {
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/system/xbin/which", "su" });
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            if (in.readLine() != null)
                return true;
            return false;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (process != null)
                process.destroy();
        }
    }
```

Now issue is that, tester installed " Hide My Root" app and with an option "hide su binary", it's performed action. 
After that when we launch my app, it's unable to identify root.
Can someone please let me know about any workaround?
I gone through blog http://bertonjulian.github.io/2015/01/30/root-detection-bypass.html but it's giving idea, but to achieve those?

Comment: If they did a good job, there would be no way for you to detect that the device is rooted. In general, trying to detect and avoid rooted devices is an "arms race" that you are likely to lose.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. Can you please write it in answer so that I can accept even?

Comment: My comment does not answer the question, so it belongs as a comment.

Comment: why don't you try to use root privileges in your app, if success, then the device is rooted. ex, execute `su`, then execute `ls /data/data` this normally will not work (access denied) unless device is rooted. however there is a possibility that "hide my root" will also disable executing `su`, then this method will fail too :)

Comment: I've tried what you said, but still not able to detect root, when it's "hide su binary" by "hide my root" app.